# Add Custom Input Field on Woocommerce Cart Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, custom-fields

I've been developing a **WooCommerce** site and I have a task where I have stuck. I need to add an extra custom input field into the cart items table.

Like for example, if a person orders **'2000 youtube views**' package, then right below the item name, I want the user to input his **Youtube video URL**.

I know I can add custom input fields on **Product Page** and can simply make them display on the **Cart Page**. But I want to take user input data onto the **Cart Page**. Each cart item will have a custom input field. So far, I have researched a lot but didn't have any success for my solution. All I found that to print the custom input field data onto the cart page added on the **Product Page.**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Adding it on the cart page seems like intentionally making it more difficult than it should be. Just use [Product Add ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons) on the individual product pages.

Comment: Please see this to solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054974/how-to-add-an-order-notes-field-in-woocommerce-cart-page/49561464#49561464

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem also. I've solved it with this. Adding the fields on the cart page like you did but with jQuery receive those values and dynamicly transfer them with a GET request, ( adding them to the submit button ) and $_GET fill them in the checkout page in a hidden input type.